# GoogleScraper files saved at?

Tags: python-3.6

I am using GoogleScraper to scrape some google results and store them in a json format

I ran this code in terminal:-

```
$ GoogleScraper -m selenium --sel-browser chrome --browser-mode headless --keyword "corolla" --output-filename ./corolla.json -v debug
```

I was expecting a .json file as output in the GoogleScrapper Folder.

But instead i do not see any file except google_scraper.db and googlescraper.log files only

I have just started coding in python scrapping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is saved under `Untitled⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨Whatever is your username ▸.json` by default.